# Compiling and running code from vscode to CMD or Windows Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Specific Question is When I'm using the Code Runner Extension or any code compile/runner Extension in VScode, it launches the running instance inside the vscode terminal. But what I wanted is the runner should compile the code and launch it into CMD or Windows Terminal instead of the vscode Terminal. How can I do this Please?

Comment: So you want it to open up CMD/Powershell as a separate process instead of inside vscode?

Comment: Exactly! how could i do that @Xosrov

Comment: Well, after looking into it a bit it seems [it's not implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22305). I've seen some people have this happen to them, but it seems most were just considered a bug. Unfortunately i don't have a windows system handy to test it... Why not just create a shortcut to open CMD, no need to rely on vscode for that!

Comment: I could do that but i have to compile the code myself everytime which makes the purpose of the coderunner useless! @Xosrov